# How to fix gstreamer error in Qt5?

Tags: mp3, qt5, gstreamer

I want to create a small mp3 player as a toy project so started with Qt for the GUI. When I try to play an mp3 file i get this error.

```
Warning: "No decoder available for type 'audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, 
mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2,
parsed=(boolean)true'." 
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."
```

I installed gstreamer and it's plugins after googling around

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav
```

But I still get the error. How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to launch the same file using gst-launch -v playbin first. This will give the exact decoder used. There is one plugin called "mad" for mp3 I guess, that might be missing. Try locating it using gst-inspect

Comment: I ran gst-launch -v playbin song.mp3
and got `Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0: No URI specified to play from.
Additional debug info:
gstplaybasebin.c(1655): gen_source_element (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
`  
and i ran `gst-inspect mad` and got `No such element or plugin 'mad'`

Comment: There is now a Qt-specific library for GStreamer named, not surprisingly, `QtGStreamer`: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/index.html.  It is available in the Ubuntu and Debian Jessie repositories under the name `qtgstreamer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After using below code it fixed.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Qt Creator 3.4.2 Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It seems [that PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/gstffmpeg-keep) doesn't have `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`.

Comment: It seems they have remove `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` after 14.04 http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly but you can try new version of it http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/multimedia/gst10-plugins-ugly.html

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto   MayBe,  Its => `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`  for you

Answer (score 1):

I tried digging a little into this and according to [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/43468/solved-qtmultimedia-media-player-example-can-t-play-any-video-on-ubuntu-14-04) thread in the Qt forums the issue seems to be that the QtMultimedia module is still using GStreamer 0.10 as a backend - and from that it needs the `gstreamer-0.10-ffmpeg` plugin which is not available in some distros anymore due to the move to libav.

If you're using a flavour of Ubuntu you can try installing `gstreamer-0.10-ffmpeg` from Doug McMahon's ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Debian8, QT5.7`, I'm executing this:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10*
```

this is not the best way, but it works.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu20.04, I solved this problem by:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```