# Unable Run Qt5 Video player example on Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt-creator, raspberry-pi2, qt5.3

I installed Qt creator(Qt5) and its examples on Raspberry pi 2 B Model. I'm running Raspbian Jessie on it. I tried to Run a Video player example but I end up with an error which was as follows:

> Starting /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/examples/multimediawidgets/build-player-Desktop-Debug/player...
>       libEGL warning: GLX/DRI2 is not supported
>       libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
>
> (player:841): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_ref_sink: assertion 'GST_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>       GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/pi/Desktop/test_video.mp4"
>       GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/pi/Desktop/test_video.mp4"
>       Warning: "No decoder available for type 'video/quicktime, variant=(string)iso'."

Please let me know how to fix these "Gstreamer" and "No decoder" things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lot of googling I can able to fix it and here is my answer.

You must edit your /etc/apt/sources.list to add new repository "deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie main non-free"
Then install the following packages

```
sudo apt-get update
# To fix key error
sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

Credits:
http://www.deb-multimedia.org/
[How to fix gstreamer error in Qt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099139/how-to-fix-gstreamer-error-in-qt5)